# Problem regarding passing a function to child process in Linux shell

Tags: bash, shellshock

I'm doing the Shellshock lab, the tutorial gives an approach to pass a function to child process by environment variable:

```
$ foo='() { echo "hello"; }'
$ export foo
$ /bin/bash
$ foo
hello
```

However, when I tried this on my Ubuntu 20.04, `foo` was not converted to a function in the child process.

```
$ foo='() { echo "hello"; }'
$ export foo
$ /bin/bash
$ foo
Command 'foo' not found, did you mean: ...
```

Is there anything I missed, or this approach only works for certain versions of bash?

Answer (score 6):

In Bash you define a [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) like so:

```bash
name () { ...; }
```

or like so:

```bash
function name { ...; }
```

and a multi-line one would look like this:

```bash
name ()
{
...
...
}
```

or like this:

```bash
function name
{
...
...
}
```

and is [exported with `-f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell) like so:

```bash
export -f name
```

So, declare your function like this:

```bash
foo () { echo "hello"; }
```

and then export it like this:

```bash
export -f foo
```

---

**Technical Notice**

That said, what you describe resembles a historical vulnerability that used to exist in Bash (particularly in the "function export" feature/mechanism syntax and subsequent parsing) about a decade ago but has been fixed long ago too so not applicable in Bash anymore unless you somehow still have an non-patched/non-updated version of Bash all that time on your system.

Please see:

- [Shellshock Attack Lab](https://seedsecuritylabs.org/Labs_16.04/Software/Shellshock/)
- [Shellshock (software bug)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug))
- [Shellshock Vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/Shellshock_-_Tudor_Enache.pdf)
- [When was the shellshock (CVE-2014-6271/7169) bug introduced, and what is the patch that fully fixes it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157381/471459)
- [Is there a short command to test if my server is secure against the shellshock bash bug?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/68168)

Answer (score 1):

Since Bash 4.4, functions are now exported as `BASH_FUNC_foo%%` instead of just as `foo`. This isn't a valid shell variable name, so you can't set it directly within Bash, but you can with other commands such as `env`, e.g., with `env BASH_FUNC_foo%%='() { echo "hello"; }' /bin/bash`.